# While passing apostrophe in company name "company's" is giving error -"Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string."

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4

Following is my code and when I tries to pass **'** in any of the field it is throwing me an error.

While passing apostrophe in company name "company's" is giving following error -

> "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string."

More Specifically

If suppose my company name is **Jam's** while passing this apostrophe it come has **Jam &#39 ; s** has the value

```
 public ActionResult OfferDocument()
    {
        List<IIFL_IB_Prospects> lstProspects = new List<IIFL_IB_Prospects>();
        InvestmentBankingParent IBParent = new InvestmentBankingParent();
        SessionParams.IBRenderMode = "0";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        IIFL_IB_Prospects IIFL_IB_Prospects;
        setUserName();
        try
        {
            ds = getProspects();

            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                IIFL_IB_Prospects = new IIFL_IB_Prospects();
                IIFL_IB_Prospects.CompanyName = Server.HtmlEncode(Convert.ToString(dr["companyname"]));
                lstProspects.Add(IIFL_IB_Prospects);
            }




            IBParent.Prospects = lstProspects;
            IBParent.recentTransaction = getKeyTransaction();
            IBParent.testimonials = getClientTestimonials();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = ex.Message + " at " + DateTime.Now + " From RecentTransaction";
            LogObj.writeLog("ErrorLogIB.txt", msg);              
        }

        obj.trackUser("View Investment Banking/Offer document");
        //return View(new IIFL_IB_Prospects(lstProspects));
        return View(IBParent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Server.HtmlEncode and Server.HtmlDecode  helped me to  solve this problem

since my code in MVC4 format, I also had to use Server.HtmlEncode and Server.HtmlDecode on the click function it of anchor tag in View .

```
<ul id="ProspectUL" class="PDF-list">
     @foreach (var documents in Model.Prospects)
    {       
   <li><a onclick="setOfferDocument('@Server.HtmlEncode(documents.CompanyName)')"  class="link-download" href="javascript:void(0)" >@Server.HtmlDecode(documents.CompanyName)</a><br /></li>
    }

 </ul>
```

I have Used Jquery ajax function to get the value from the server side..

```
 function setOfferDocument(document) 
{
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/OfferDocument/setOfferDocument",
            data: { "document": document },
            success: function (val) { }
        });




        else if (document == "Jam&amp;#39;s Infraprojects Limited") {

            var url = "../OfferDocument/OffcerDocumentCAPACITE";
            window.location.href = url;
        }
        else {

            var url = "../OfferDocument/PublicOffering";
            window.location.href = url;
        }


    }
```

Please Note 
this has been encoded two time one from server side and another in view side-
hence it is 
 Jam &a mp;#39;s
if it is encoded only once then the value
Jam&#39 ;s